# Open Form in Access from Cross Table Query

Tags: ms-access

Here is the scenario. I have a database that is single function basically to manage documents. There are two tables that I am dealing with for this example.

Table 1: Table of Documents with the following fields `DOCUMENT_NUM`, PK; `DOCUMENT_NAME`; etc. One-to-many relationship to Table 1 with referential integrity based on `DOCUMENT_NUM`

Table 2: Table of revision history of documents with fields `DOCUMENT_NUM`, PK; `REVISION_DATE`; `REVISION_NUM`.

I have a form that enters in the information for Table 1, and another form that enters in information into Table 2 pulling in `DOCUMENT_NUM` off the criteria in Form 1.

**My problem**: I have a search form that I want to be able to open Form 1 that is bound to Table 1 by searching for not only parameters that are in Table 1 but also in Table 2. Example: Search for documents revised between ##/##/#### and ##/##/#### but will open Form 1 with the "DOCUMENT_NUM", "DOCUMENT_NAME", etc. However I cannot do the search since From 1 is bound to Table 1 and the information I am querying against is in Table 2.

The Search uses `DoCmd.OpenForm "Documents",,,strQuery` where `strQuery = "1=1 AND [SOPS].[SOP_NUMBER] = 'QA-001' AND [SOP_REVISIONS].[REVISION_DATE] >= #12/02/2011# AND [SOP_REVISIONS].[REVISION_DATE] <= #12/02/2012#"`

([SOPS] == Table 1 && [SOP_REVISIONS] == Table 2)

Comment: Why do you need `1=1`? Do you expect your code to run in some kind of parallel universe?

Comment: @ZevSpitz 1=1 is frequently used when building a WHERE statement dynamically. You can start with a string `WHERE 1=1` and append `AND ...` rather than trying to figure out which is the first additional statement and / or stripping a subsequent string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
strQuery = "1=1 AND [SOPS].[SOP_NUMBER] = 'QA-001' " _
    & "AND DOCUMENT_NUM IN (" _
    & "   SELECT DOCUMENT_NUM FROM [SOP_REVISIONS] " _
    & "   WHERE [SOP_REVISIONS].[REVISION_DATE] >= #12/02/2011# " _
    & "   AND [SOP_REVISIONS].[REVISION_DATE] <= #12/02/2012#)"
```

In other words, use a subquery to get the related DOCUMENT_NUM from [SOP_REVISIONS].

Comment: I am having a hard time getting something like that to work. Can you do a nested statement like that when you are using it for the Where condition of the DoCmd.OpenForm action?

Comment: I tested with this `DoCmd.OpenForm "tbljournaltitles", , , "JournalTitleskey in (select JournalTitleskey from tbljournals where crdate>#2012/11/13#)"` which is simpler than your query, but along the same lines and it returned the expected number of records. Where are you having the problem? Perhaps you could use year, month, day for the dates?

Comment: Your solution worked. I made a silly mistake. Thank you for your help. I didn't know you could do nested SQL in a command like this.